# Hide an Automation to avoid been erased from marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have several automations created and I dont want this to can be midified or erased by the users working on SFMC.

There is a way to protect or hide this automations (i.e.created by superadmin,etc..)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If a SFMC user has access to delete Automations in general, this user can then delete any of the Automations in that Business Unit.

There isn't a way to hide them, although you could create a folder called '*DoNotTouch*' and ask coworkers **not to** wreak havoc with anything in it.

Overall I think you have two options here..

**1)** You remove the access to perform Delete operation on Automation on their Roles, but understand they can still Edit them. Or remove access to create/edit/delete Automations in general.

**2)** You keep your Automations in top-level BU and revoke other users access to modify/delete Automations in that BU only.

[image: RoleConfig]